# Entering form modal message loop without actual form showing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have an WinForms application with one main form `MainForm`. This application has some scheduled operation being called in some intervals. This operation takes a lot of time to execute so it is launched in background thread. When operation is running form with progress is shown - `LoaderForm`. This form is shown as modal via `loader.ShowDialog(mainForm)`; loader starts operation when shown.

This works fine unless operation starts when:

- `MainForm` is minimized in taskbar
- `MainForm` is hidden to tray (not shown in taskbar at all)

In such cases I need **not** to show `LoaderForm` unless application is activated. The problem is the `LoaderForm` is shown even when `MainForm` is not visually visible without proper handling.

What is the easiest way to achieve desired behavior?

---

#### Example code

```
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles uiTimer.Tick
        uiTimer.Enabled = False
        Using loader = New LoaderForm()
            loader.ShowDialog(Me)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class LoaderForm

    Private Sub LoaderForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles worker.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Another case of [Synchronization by Modal](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Synchronization-by-Modal.aspx).

Comment: Modal forms don't work when their visibility is false. You should redesign your approach so that it works regardless of whether you have a modal dialogue displayed or not.  The Modal should not launch the backgroundworker.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Acknowledged provided example is bad design pattern. However I believe even if job would be started directly by the timer and loader shown afterwards/on-job-start event/etc. the problem would be still the same. I mean - I cannot achieve described behavior without major refactoring of the process, right? (e.g. using loader control instead of form)

Comment: @mancze - ` I cannot achieve described behavior without major refactoring of the process, right`.  Exactly, because of what I said...Modal does not work when visibility is false.  What you are doing now will not work at all.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Than could you guide me how to properly hook the "show loader" event to main form? Let's assume I have method to detect whether operation is running or not. Dialog handled it for me as it created it's own message loop which captured everything - mouse, keyboard, hotkeys, etc... I need to disable any user interaction with the `MainForm`.

Comment: "I need to disable any user interaction with the MainForm"  How about just setting the Enabled() property of the main form to false?

Comment: I would try an observer pattern.  Kickoff the backgroundworker from a non-modal form (your primary Form should do) and subscribe to it to be notified when it's complete.  As long as the backgroundworker is in progress and the UI is active then you can create a seperate (as in not coupled to the background thread) Modal dialogue with a loading Icon.  Coding this up is non-trivial.  You can start by looking into IObservable<T>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782981(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

We can create a new modal message loop without actually showing a modal dialog by calling **undocumented** Win32 APIs `BeginModalMessageLoop` and `EndModalMessageLoop`.

Note: *These apis are undocumented, so we are not supposed to actually use them. You should only use these as a last resort.*

```
    //Capture method reference using reflection
    _methodBeginLoop = FindMethod(typeof (Application), "BeginModalMessageLoop");
    _methodEndLoop = FindMethod(typeof (Application), "EndModalMessageLoop");

       private static MethodInfo FindMethod(Type type, string methodName)
            {
                const BindingFlags BINDING_FLAGS = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

                MemberInfo[] members = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Method, BINDING_FLAGS,
                    new MethodFilter(methodName).Matches, null);

                if (members.Length == 1)
                    return members[0] as MethodInfo;
                return null;
            }
```

**For Blocking the inputs on main form, we can use**

```
Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new Action(() =>
 {
   _methodBeginLoop.Invoke(null, null);
 }
```

**For UnBlocking the inputs on main form, we can use**

```
Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new Action(() =>
 {
   _methodEndLoop.Invoke(null, null);
 }
```

Comment: Of course these are not Win32 APIs, they are part of the Windows Forms library.  If they were Win32 functions you would call them using `DllImport` not reflection.